# set filetype and comment key map with .s file

Tags: linux, assembly, vim

Im woking with `.s` file. Although this file is asm file, but it is not same as `.asm` file (comment begins by `--`, not `#`).

So when I open a `.s` file, it shows as asm file. How can I change filetype to display correctly (blue color after `--` sign)?

And also, I have mapped `F1` in `vimrc` to comment as below:

```
if (@% =~ "\.s") "if file is .s
   map <F1> :<ESC>0i-- <ESC>j
endif
```

This method works well with other files, but not with `.s` file. The comment sign is `#` because I map `F1` is `#` previously.

Can you help me?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Standing on the shoulders of giants

I would *highly* recommend commenting plugin like [commentary](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary) (which I use), [Nerd Commenter](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdcommenter), [EnhCommentify](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=23), [tComment](https://github.com/tomtom/tcomment_vim), ..., [etc](http://vimawesome.com/?q=comment). There is no shame in using a plugin. Especially since comment toggling is deceptively more complicated than expected.

#### Customizing Commentary.vim

Simply set `'commentstring'` to your comment style for your filetype. Most often this is already setup for you if Vim recognizes your filetype. See `:h 'commentstring'`.

Example of changing `'commentstring'` for php. Add the following to `~/.vim/ftplugin/asm.vim`:

```
if expand('%:t') =~# '\.s$'
  set commentstring=--\ %s
endif
```

Or if you rather everything in your `vimrc` file:

```
autocmd FileType asm if expand('%:t') =~# '\.s$' | set commentstring=--\ %s | endif
```

You can set the toggle comment command to `<f1>` like so:

```
nmap <f1> <Plug>CommentaryLine
```

However commentary are much closer the the home row and do not conflict with any native mappings.

Note: I use commentary this may not work for other comment plugins. As always, read the documentation.

#### Syntax

You may need to change you syntax file to show lines starting with `--` as comments. Add the following to `~/.vim/after/syntax/asm.vim`:

```
syntax match asmComment /--\_s.*$/
```

#### But I don't or can't use a plugin

Sometimes using a plugin isn't an option, but you should know that (de-)commenting is a lot trickier than it first seems. Especially if you need to do it across multiple filetypes. Plugins like commentary.vim let you comment multiple lines at a time or use a motion, e.g. `gcip`.

The simplest approach. Comment only:

```
autocmd FileType asm nnoremap <buffer> <F1> gI-- <ESC>j
```

Now for some toggling with an map-expression:

```
autocmd FileType asm nnoremap <buffer> <expr> <f1> getline('.') =~ '^\s*--\_s' ? "^3"_x+" : "gI-- \<esc>+"
```

I have also created a [naive commentary.vim-style](https://gist.github.com/PeterRincker/13bde011c01b7fc188c5) comment toggle mappings. Put the following in your `vimrc` file:

```
nnoremap gcc :<c-u>.,.+<c-r>=v:count<cr>call <SID>toggleComment()<cr>
nnoremap gc :<c-u>set opfunc=<SID>commentOp<cr>g@
xnoremap gc :call <SID>toggleComment()<cr>

function! s:commentOp(...)
  '[,']call s:toggleComment()
endfunction

function! s:toggleComment() range
  let comment = substitute(get(b:, 'commentstring', &commentstring), '\s*\(%s\)\s*', '%s', '')
  let pattern = '\V' . printf(escape(comment, '\'), '\(\s\{-}\)\s\(\S\.\{-}\)\s\=')
  let replace = '\1\2'
  if getline('.') !~ pattern
    let indent = matchstr(getline('.'), '^\s*')
    let pattern = '^' . indent . '\zs\(\s*\)\(\S.*\)'
    let replace = printf(comment, '\1 \2' . (comment =~ '%s$' ? '' : ' '))
  endif
  for lnum in range(a:firstline, a:lastline)
    call setline(lnum, substitute(getline(lnum), pattern, replace, ''))
  endfor
endfunction
```

#### More information

```
:h 'commentstring'
:h :set
:h filetype
:h new-filetype
:h ftdetect
:h ftplugins
:h after-directory
:h :syn-match
:h :autocmd
:h :map-expression
:h :map-local
```

Comment: Thank you. It works but not as my expectation. I modify commentary.vim to map F1 for CommentaryLine, it works now.

Comment: I also can not change my syntax file because Im running in server, I dont have permission to do that. Do you have another way? Sorry for many question.

Comment: Hi there. I find a simply way. Just need asm.vim as you said, but add "nmap <F1> <ESC>0i-- <ESC>j". Comment works correctly now. LOL