# Vim place comment uncomment in very beginning of line shortcut

Tags: vim

I know how to comment a line in vim by doing `Shift-I-//`. This ends up in something like:

```
    //int a = 1;
```

Instead, I would like to put comment in the very beginning of line, like:

```
//    int a = 1;
```

Currently I can do this by `0-i-//`.

May I ask for a shortcut like i.e. `Shift-0-//` (or even shorter)?

I installed nerdcommenter, tried all the [default maps](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdcommenter) and none does that?

I did:

let g:NERDDefaultAlign = 'left'

And its not bad, but I still would like to have the comments on the very beginning of the line.

Comment: `Shift-0-//` is not a key shorter then `0-i-//` so whats your goal exactly? You already know how to do what you ask for. Just looking for a simple mapping?  (`:h map` ). There are a lot of questions about that. Please search for mappings here or on your favourite search engine or provide more information for your question

Comment: Related post: [set filetype and comment key map with .s file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41755704/438329). I strong recommend you look into a plugin if you do this often or are able to

Comment: ok, I installed `nerdcommenter`, tried all the default maps and none does what I asked?

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo Well, it depends how you count. The way I count it `Shift-0` is shorter because I do it in parallel, using both hands ), so one key stroke per hand, while `0-i` is two key strokes on the right hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not pick a popular comment plugin? I use `nerdcommenter`, and I am satisfied with it.

If you want to do the comment/uncomment toggle on your own, you may want to know `gI`. Like:

```
nnoremap whatever gI//<esc>
```

I still recommend the plugin, because even if build your own function check if there is `//` on BOL, to toggle comment, it adds/removes only `//`. If you opened a python file, or shell script or vimscript, you cannot use this mapping any longer. The plugin checked the filetype, it is convenient. Well you can of course write all things by yourself, to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: ok, I installed nerdcommenter, tried all the default maps and none does what I asked?

Answer (score 1):

put this in your vimrc

```
nnoremap <leader>/ 0i//<esc>
```

Now every time you press `<leader>/` you will comment the line the way you want.

(If you don't have a `<leader>` yet, look up :h leader and carry on from there).

Comment: I'm posting this as a comment because it might not technically be part of the answer, but I see that you also said in the title that you want to be able to uncomment lines too, just map leader and a key to 0xx (jump to start of line, delete a char twice)